# Two App.js in Module Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have created two java Script files  app and  app2 in a folder but when i wanted to debug (app) in visual code it debug the app2 instead.
What actually happens under hood??

Answer (score 1):

> follow  this github link and require more info just let me know
>   and can i also know your file structure.
>    https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation

Comment: Thanks.. for your help :)